# Insert Into MYSQL DB using jquery/ajax 500 internal server error

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I'm inserting radio checked data values into mysql db with php/jquery and ajax while inserting values i'm getting internal server 500 error...

Any help is appreciated Thanks!

**Html Code**

```
<div>
    <input class="radio_div_clicked" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?> name="radio_section" id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"/>
    <p><?php echo $row['name'];?></p>
    <button id="add_feed">Add</button>
</div>
```

**JQUERY CODE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('body').delegate('#add_feed','click',function(){

    var radio_div_clicked = $('input:radio[name=radio_section]:checked').val();
    $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"index.php",
            cache: false,
            data:{
                insert_section:1,
                radio_div_clicked:radio_div_clicked
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
                alert('Successfully Inserted Into Table');
            }
        });
    }

});
</script>
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php 
    $con = @mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('failed to connect server');
    $db = mysql_select_db('demo',$con) or die('failed to select db');
    if(isset($_POST['insert_section']))
    {
        $radio_div_clicked = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['radio_div_clicked']);
        $sql = mysql_query("insert into test(name) values($radio_div_clicked)";
        if($sql)
        {
            echo "Successfully Inserted Into Table";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Failed To Insert Value Into Table"
        }
    }
?>
<?php 
    mysql_close ($con);
?>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @DevAlien 500 Internal Server Error 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql query `values($radio_div_clicked)";` did't closed properly, should be

```
$sql = mysql_query("insert into test(name) values('".$radio_div_clicked."')");
```

If you're using chrome, click on network tab, and click the requested link. Then, again click on preview or response header. Usually the details errors showing up there.